# Pandas MultiIndex in which one factor is an Enum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, enums

I'm having trouble working with a dataframe whose columns are a multiindex *in which one of the iterables is an Enum*. Consider the code:

```
MyEnum = Enum("MyEnum", "A B")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables=[MyEnum, [1, 2]]))
```

This raises

```
TypeError: 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument.
```

This can be worked around by instead putting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables=[
    pd.Series(MyEnum, dtype="category"),
    [1, 2]
]))
```

but then appending a row with

```
df.append({(MyEnum.A, 1): "abc", (MyEnum.B, 2): "xyz"}, ignore_index=True)
```

raises the same `TypeError` as before.

I've tried various variations on this theme, with no success. (No problems occur if the columns is *not* a multiindex, but is an enum.)

(Note that I can dodge this by using an IntEnum instead of an Enum. But then, my columns, simply appear as numbers---this is why I wanted to use an Enum in the first place, as opposed to ints.)

Many thanks!

Comment: Rather than appending try this `df.loc[0,[(MyEnum.A,1),(MyEnum.B,2)]] = 'abc','xyz'`

Comment: Thanks, this works, though it's a bit more error-prone, as it's order-dependent (the order of the indexers must match the order of the rhs). Also, it requires me to grab a value to use as the row-indexer.

Comment: its better to ask this question in github.

Comment: Thanks, done: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21298